# Crystal reports cannot show data

Tags: crystal-reports

I have tried in Crystal ver. 10 and 12. I was able to create reports from my database until last week. Since there, I was able to see the tables, views in crystal's database connection wizard, but no data is generated. In field explorer the field and field types are showing correctly but no data shown while browse the data!

What could be the cause of this issue? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you add some more details to the question? What type of database are you using? What do you mean by "no data is generated"? Your report doesn't return any data, or simply selecting "Browse Field" doesn't return any values?

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly your question is incomplete. Try to add more detail
```

If you don't see any data in `Browse Data` it doesn't mean that CR is behaving in a wrong way, May be your data connection is wrong like you may be connecting to wrong database.

If you have database object, At this point I would suggest you to take the SQL query generated by crystal report (`Database --> Query`) and fire the query against the database.

Also try to check whether database has any data.

```
If you need more assistance provide more info on what you are doing and what you are getting
```

Comment: Why are you marking sections of your answer as `code` when it isn't?

Comment: I just want to highlight few things in the answer.. so making sections. Is this a wrong practice?

Comment: Use **bold** text.  Wrap the words with \** apostrophes \**.